# What does "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT" means?

Tags: android, retrofit2, gson

I'm facing this very basic issue as I'm parsing according to response. Can some trace where I'm doing some thing wrong. I'm using GSON adapter with retrofit 2.

```
[
    {
        "date": "2018-07-17",
        "trip": [
            {
                "id": 381,
                "trip_address": "Dubai, United Arab Emirates",
                "trip_created_by": "auth0|5a7dafcf5c679b17810dbd88",
                "trip_arrival_datetime": "17-07-2018 21:03",
                "trip_departure_datetime": null,
                "trip_country": null,
                "trip_city": null,
                "trip_state": null,
                "trip_location_longitude": "67.00113640",
                "trip_location_latitude": "24.86073430",
                "trip_status": "pending",
                "created_at": "2018-06-24 12:03:20",
                "updated_at": "2018-06-24 12:03:20"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My model classes:

Retrofit interface:

```
@GET("meetup-by-date/{user_id}/{date}")
    Single<List<MeetupResponse>> getMeetups(@Path("user_id") String userId, @Path("date") String date);`
```

Response model:

```
public class MeetupResponse {
    @SerializedName("date")
    private String date;

    @SerializedName("meetup")
    private List<MeetUp> meetups;

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public List<MeetUp> getTrips() {
        return meetups;
    }

    public void setTrips(List<MeetUp> trips) {
        this.meetups = trips;
    }
}
```

Comment: BEGIN_OBJECT means it found `{ }` before it found `[ ]` It means that your response is trying to parse an array but the level failing is actually an object

Answer (score 0):

You have a malformed JSON response somewhere.

If you post the full log trace along with the retrofit log of the response body, I could point out where specifically is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using wrong key `meetup`. change `meetup` to `trip` .i.e, change `@SerializedName("meetup")` to `@SerializedName("trip")`

You may use the following pojo classes

```
    public class MeetupResponse {

@SerializedName("date")
@Expose
private String date;
@SerializedName("trip")
@Expose
private List<Trip> trip = null;

public String getDate() {
return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
this.date = date;
}

public List<Trip> getTrip() {
return trip;
}

public void setTrip(List<Trip> trip) {
this.trip = trip;
}

}
```

and this

```
    public class Trip {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("trip_address")
@Expose
private String tripAddress;
@SerializedName("trip_created_by")
@Expose
private String tripCreatedBy;
@SerializedName("trip_arrival_datetime")
@Expose
private String tripArrivalDatetime;
@SerializedName("trip_departure_datetime")
@Expose
private Object tripDepartureDatetime;
@SerializedName("trip_country")
@Expose
private Object tripCountry;
@SerializedName("trip_city")
@Expose
private Object tripCity;
@SerializedName("trip_state")
@Expose
private Object tripState;
@SerializedName("trip_location_longitude")
@Expose
private String tripLocationLongitude;
@SerializedName("trip_location_latitude")
@Expose
private String tripLocationLatitude;
@SerializedName("trip_status")
@Expose
private String tripStatus;
@SerializedName("created_at")
@Expose
private String createdAt;
@SerializedName("updated_at")
@Expose
private String updatedAt;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getTripAddress() {
return tripAddress;
}

public void setTripAddress(String tripAddress) {
this.tripAddress = tripAddress;
}

public String getTripCreatedBy() {
return tripCreatedBy;
}

public void setTripCreatedBy(String tripCreatedBy) {
this.tripCreatedBy = tripCreatedBy;
}

public String getTripArrivalDatetime() {
return tripArrivalDatetime;
}

public void setTripArrivalDatetime(String tripArrivalDatetime) {
this.tripArrivalDatetime = tripArrivalDatetime;
}

public Object getTripDepartureDatetime() {
return tripDepartureDatetime;
}

public void setTripDepartureDatetime(Object tripDepartureDatetime) {
this.tripDepartureDatetime = tripDepartureDatetime;
}

public Object getTripCountry() {
return tripCountry;
}

public void setTripCountry(Object tripCountry) {
this.tripCountry = tripCountry;
}

public Object getTripCity() {
return tripCity;
}

public void setTripCity(Object tripCity) {
this.tripCity = tripCity;
}

public Object getTripState() {
return tripState;
}

public void setTripState(Object tripState) {
this.tripState = tripState;
}

public String getTripLocationLongitude() {
return tripLocationLongitude;
}

public void setTripLocationLongitude(String tripLocationLongitude) {
this.tripLocationLongitude = tripLocationLongitude;
}

public String getTripLocationLatitude() {
return tripLocationLatitude;
}

public void setTripLocationLatitude(String tripLocationLatitude) {
this.tripLocationLatitude = tripLocationLatitude;
}

public String getTripStatus() {
return tripStatus;
}

public void setTripStatus(String tripStatus) {
this.tripStatus = tripStatus;
}

public String getCreatedAt() {
return createdAt;
}

public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

public String getUpdatedAt() {
return updatedAt;
}

public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt) {
this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
}

}
```